# Is there any way to store cookies in django which is independent to browser?

Tags: python, django, flash, cookies

Is there any way in django to store cookies which is independent to browser ?
is there any technique just like what flash SharedObject does ..?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "indepent to browser "?
Like if the use logs in in another browser, that the cookies will be there?

Comment: i mean ..like in flash by sharedObject we can save the cookies globally.Which later can be access in any browser.

Check this example in flash http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/
.. so is there any technique in django.?

hope you understand what i want.

Answer (score 2):

A Django view receives an instance of [HttpRequest](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/1.2/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest) as its first argument.  That object has an attribute [COOKIES](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/1.2/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.COOKIES) which is, and I quote,

> A standard Python dictionary
>   containing all cookies. Keys and
>   values are strings.

You can of course save that dictionary in any way you like (e.g., pickle it into a blob of bytes and save that blob as a suitable attribute of a suitable entity, etc, etc).

Conversely, when you instantiate an [HttpResponse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) to return as the view's result, you can call its [set_cookie](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.set_cookie) method one or more times to set on it any cookies you may want to set.

Answer (score 1):

As it's explain in the link you give in your comment, Shared Objects are not stored as browser cookies, they are completely managed by the Flash Player. That's why they are independent of the browser.

So the answer is **no**, you can't store a cookie that is independent of the browser with Django (or any other web framework).

A possible solution is, if your visitor need to log to your site, you can store the info on the server, probably in a database. But if you don't required users to be log in, it will not work. Your other solution is to use Flash only to store the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set cookie, so that it would be available in all browsers on computer. You can do it in Flash, because it is external library (one for all browsers).